# Help setting up integral for circulation

Tags: integration, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

I just need a bit of help with a problem. I'm being asked to evaluate the circulation of a velocity field. I've just finished calculating the curl of the vector field in question and I know from my text that I need $\int_{S}^{ } (\mathbf{curl \ u})\cdot \mathbf{n} \ dA$, but there are no examples in the book of this set up. Can someone help me set this up so I can perform the integration?

The question is below. I can see and visualise the boundaries, I'm just not sure how to go about setting up the integral, I'll be fine doing the actual integration.

[image: Question]

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: It will be the sum of four integrals, one for each piece of the boundary that you can conveniently parameterize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a line integral $\int_C \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{l}$ is the integral of the **tangential** component of the velocity with respect to arclength along the contour. 
Traversed anticlockwise we have 
 $$\int_C \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{l} = \int_{C_1} \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{l}+\int_{C_2} \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{l}+ \int_{C_3} \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{l}+\int_{C_4} \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{l}$$

where

$$C_1 = \left\{(r,\theta) : \, r = a , \frac{\pi}6 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}, \,\,d \vec{\mathcal{l}} = -a\vec{e}_\theta d\theta\\ C_2 = \left\{(r,\theta) : \, a \leqslant r\leqslant 2a , \,\theta =  \frac{\pi}{6}\right\},  \,\,d \vec{\mathcal{l}} = \vec{e}_r dr\\ C_3 = \left\{(r,\theta) : \, r = 2a , \frac{\pi}6 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}, \,\,d \vec{\mathcal{l}} = 2a\vec{e}_\theta d\theta\\ C_4 = \left\{(r,\theta) : \, a \leqslant r \leqslant  2a , \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}, \,\,d \vec{\mathcal{l}} = -\vec{e}_r dr$$

Thus,

$$\int_C \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{l} = -\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} u_\theta(a,\theta) a \, d\theta + \int_{a}^{2a} u_r(r,\pi/6) \, dr   + \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} u_\theta(2a,\theta) 2a \, d\theta -  \int_{a}^{2a} u_r(r,\pi/2) \, dr$$

Since this is a two-dimensional velocity field, the only non-vanishing component of the curl is $\omega_z$ in the direction normal to the plane.  By Stokes' (Green's) theorem, the circulation could also be computed as the double integral over the sector bounded by $C$,

$$\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} \int_{a}^{2a} \omega_z \, r \, dr \, d\theta$$

Comment: Beautiful! Very helpful. I shall have a go at this after lunch :)

Comment: Worked out perfectly! Well, the algebra was quite nasty integrating dr, I had to have Wolfram tell me what simplification I was aiming for, but I got there in the end with all the intermediate steps worked out. 

The tough thing for me is this is an Open University course so it's all distance learning. I literally have nobody to talk to when I get stuck. The only other person at work who's done this sort of thing hasn't done it in 20 years and I'm doing things harder than he ever did. I have a tutor on Spires with a maths degree and these keep stumping him as well! Many thanks!

Comment: @C.Wolfe: I'm happy it worked out.  You can always come here with fluid dynamics problems that are of a mathematical nature. Physics.SE is another potential resource for you. A relatively small number of users are active in this area here but it should suffice. Note that the community is getting stricter about questions showing context / effort as described [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510).  Adhering to this should prevent downvoting leading to closure leading to deletion.